# MySQL Query month selection error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use this query to cover a month, but I can't get it to work.

```
SELECT GVA14.COD_VENDED, GVA14.RAZON_SOCI
FROM GVA14
GROUP BY GVA14.COD_VENDED, GVA14.RAZON_SOCI, GVA14.FECHA_ALTA
HAVING (((DATE(GVA14.FECHA_ALTA))=Month(curDate())));
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't this solve it:

```
SELECT GVA14.COD_VENDED, GVA14.RAZON_SOCI, GVA14.FECHA_ALTA
FROM GVA14
WHERE Month(GVA14.FECHA_ALTA)=Month(curDate())
    and Year(GVA14.FECHA_ALTA)=Year(curDate())
GROUP BY GVA14.COD_VENDED, GVA14.RAZON_SOCI, GVA14.FECHA_ALTA
```

Comment: That's great, but it shows all the years... Like december 2009, december 2011

Comment: There, added the year clause also

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY is used only with aggregate functions. But I don't see any function being used in your query. Also, Having is used with aggregate functions. It would be helpful if you could state what exactly you want to fetch from your database, and what are the columns (at least the relevant ones) in your database.

Comment: The columns are COD_VENDED, a text column, RAZON_SOCI also a text column and FECHA_ALTA a date time column. I want a list of all the RAZON_SOCIs each COD_VENDEDOR has created this month.