# MySQL Query Select Month Error

Tags: mysql

I've built this query to give me a list of how much IMPORTE each COD_ZONA has done in the current month. The date is indicated by FECHA_EMIS and COD_CLIENT is the link between the two tables.

```
SELECT GVA12.FECHA_EMIS, GVA12.IMPORTE, GVA14.COD_ZONA
FROM GVA12 INNER JOIN GVA14 ON GVA12.COD_CLIENT = GVA14.COD_CLIENT
GROUP BY GVA12.FECHA_EMIS, GVA12.IMPORTE, GVA14.COD_ZONA
HAVING (((GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Month(curDate())));
```

It gives an empty table.

---

@bluefeet this is how I would like the final table

```
COD_ZONA            IMPORTE
1                   1457.56
16                  127.45
```

Comment: You created a new post relating the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740851/mysql-query-month-selection-error/13740925#13740925

Comment: Yep, but I haven't worked out how to fix it yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use this, apply the `Month()` function to both the `GVA12.FECHA_EMIS` and the `curDate()`:

```
SELECT GVA12.FECHA_EMIS, GVA12.IMPORTE, GVA14.COD_ZONA
FROM GVA12 INNER JOIN GVA14 
  ON GVA12.COD_CLIENT = GVA14.COD_CLIENT
WHERE Month(GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Month(curDate())
GROUP BY GVA12.FECHA_EMIS, GVA12.IMPORTE, GVA14.COD_ZONA
```

If you want to compare both month and year, then I would use:

```
SELECT GVA12.FECHA_EMIS, GVA12.IMPORTE, GVA14.COD_ZONA
FROM GVA12 INNER JOIN GVA14 
  ON GVA12.COD_CLIENT = GVA14.COD_CLIENT
WHERE Month(GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Month(curDate())
  AND Year(GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Year(curDate())
GROUP BY GVA12.FECHA_EMIS, GVA12.IMPORTE, GVA14.COD_ZONA
```

This would make sure that the month and year are equal.

If you want a `sum()` then you would use:

```
SELECT GVA14.COD_ZONA, sum(GVA12.IMPORTE)
FROM GVA12 INNER JOIN GVA14 
  ON GVA12.COD_CLIENT = GVA14.COD_CLIENT
WHERE Month(GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Month(curDate())
  AND Year(GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Year(curDate())
GROUP BY GVA14.COD_ZONA
```

Comment: So if I add another row after the month one using year, it will select current year?

Comment: If you are using a `WHERE` clause that checks both month and year, then for example if you check against today, you will only get records from December, 2012

Comment: Great! Is there any way to sum the IMPORTE of each COD_ZONA? There are 39 of them. So that the final result is a total for each COD_ZONA. Thanks

Comment: @CalvT see my edit, You will sum the importe and group by the cod_zona

Answer (score 0):

GVA12.FECHA_EMIS storing month or full date? You are comparing with current month.

```
HAVING (((GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Month(curDate())));
```

Comment: then how it will return results when you compare full date with month

Comment: True... So how can I change that?

Comment: try HAVING Month(GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Month(curDate());